# What is the field name for MID, TID of Authorize.net for knowing it is from NPS

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

What is the field name for MID, TID of Authorize.net for knowing it is from NPS.

NPS will provide unique Merchant ID (MID) and Terminal ID (TID) numbers.

So while passing fields along with x_Login, x_Amount, x_cust_id adn others 
I want to pass Merchant ID (MID) and Terminal ID (TID) values, but not sure
to what field values  it should be passed with.

Couldn't get much information either from these link
http://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/CP_guide.pdf?

Answer (score 0):

The Merchant ID is a gateway configured parameter and there is no API access to the information. Instead you will need to contact customer service to make changes.